# Writing files to an Airport Extreme using afp

Tags: 12.04, file-sharing, apple

Using Nautilus I can connect from Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) to my Apple Airport Extreme using user & password without a problem. I can read, browse folders and delete files. However I cannot write files, the file is created, but the contents of the file are not transferred.

The transfer fails with the error message "kFPMiscErr" which I think means that "authentication has already been established" ?.

I have tried the command line tools for access using AFP but these do not work either.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect to it using SMB protocol. I tried it and now I can connect from Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit to Apple Time Capsule, read, write and delete files on it. 
I read this discussion on Apple discussion:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2691164?start=0&tstart=0

Before using the smb protocol (i.e. with the afp protocol) I got:
 **kFPMiscError**
If I tried to copy some files on it.

Example
smb://user@num1.num2.num3.num4

The problem is: it works just if you are on the same network!:(
From a non local network through the protocol afp on Ubuntu 12.04 I found you can copy or move files already written in the Time Capsule folders. Anyway the goal would be copy files not empty on it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

in 13.04 afp://name@adress works by default